# Writing to excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas

I have 3 lists of 192 values. I've just learnt about pandas and extracting to excel but still got problems working with it.

So basically what I'm doing now is making a numpy array with those 3 lists in it. After that I want to make 3 columns in excel, every column one list. Could somebody help me adjust my code?

Error I'm getting:

```
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

allresults= numpy.array([[listOfRandomizedConditions,inputsUser,reactiontimesUser]])
to_write2 = pandas.DataFrame({'Conditions': allresults[0], 'Inputs': allresults[1], 'Reactionstimes': allresults[2]})
to_write2.to_excel('ResultsofUsers.xlsx',sheet_name = str(participantnumber), index = False, startrow=3,startcol=2)
```

Example of what those 3 lists look like:

```
listOfRandomizedConditions =  
['IncongruentNegPos',
 'CongruentPositief',
 'CongruentPositief', ...]
inputsUser = 
    ['j', 
     'f',         
     nan,
     nan,
     nan,
     nan, ...]
reactiontimesUser =  
 [nan,
 nan,
 0.3369625639170408, ...]
```

Comment: `all-results` has only one row, so 1 is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you are creating `allresults`. Instead of list of list you just need one list. Delete extra brackets `[` and `]`:

```
allresults = numpy.array([listOfRandomizedConditions,inputsUser,reactiontimesUser])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've made a list of list, which you didn't want. So change

```
allresults= numpy.array([[listOfRandomizedConditions,inputsUser,reactiontimesUser]])
```

to

```
allresults= numpy.array([listOfRandomizedConditions,inputsUser,reactiontimesUser])
```